# What does Vlad Zamfir mean by 'the fork-choice rule is stateful'?

Tags: mining, casper, forks

Does he mean the rule to determine the next blockchain requires knowing the state of currently bonded validators?

> [This “out-of-band authentication only necessarily once” property is
>   what Vitalik calls weak subjectivity. In this context information is
>   said to be “objective” if it can be verified in a protocol-defined
>   manner, while it is “subjective” if it must be authenticated via
>   extra-protocol means. In weakly subjective consensus protocols, ***the
>   fork-choice rule is stateful***, and clients must initialize (and
>   possibly sometimes renew) the information that their fork-choice rule
>   uses to authenticate the consensus. In our case, this entails
>   identifying the currently bonded validators (or, more probably a
>   cryptographic hash of the validator list).](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/01/introducing-casper-friendly-ghost/)